# Use a variable as a autofilter condition

Tags: excel, vba

this is the code that I am using but its producing error object required error. is there any way to keep filtered data by using a parameter in a another sheet to first filter the data and then delete all the rows that is not in the filter.

```
Sub KeepOnlyFiltered()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow
    Dim Criteria As String
    Dim Filter As String
    Set Filter = Worksheets("Controls").Range("A1").Value
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("XX")
    Worksheets("XX").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Filter.Value
    lastRow = 300
    For iCntr = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Rows(iCntr).Hidden = True Then Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Does that even compile? It's missing a `Next` at the end.

Comment: Are the worksheets in different workbooks? Which worksheet is in the workbook containing this code? Are both? What kind of data is in `A1` of `Controls`? Strings, numbers, dates,...etc.? Let's say you used `Filter = CStr(Worksheets("Controls").Range("A1").Value)`. Then you could filter the 'opposite' with `..., Criteria1:="<>" & Filter` and delete the filtered data with `rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete xlShiftUp` in one go, if the expressions `Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Worksheets("XX").Range("A1").CurrentRegion` reference the range of interest.

Comment: You dim the "Filter" as string. So I think, you should use `Filter = Worksheets("Controls").Range("A1").Value` instead of `Set Filter = Worksheets("Controls").Range("A1").Value`. Then in the filtering process, use `Criteria1:=Filter` instead of `Criteria1:=Filter.Value`. Not tested in my side. On the other hand, if you dim the Filter as range, then `Set Filter = Worksheets("Controls").Range("A1")` instead of `Set Filter = Worksheets("Controls").Range("A1").Value`. Then in the filtering process it still the same code : `Criteria1:=Filter.Value`